# Variabile from constructor to method - PHP

Tags: php, oop

i am pretty new in PHP OOP so I'm sorry if this question is noobish.

I choosing client langauge in constructor of the class. It looks like:

```
$lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
         $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
         if(isSet($lang))
                setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
            else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
                $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
            else
                $lang = 'cs';
        switch ($lang) 
        {
            case 'sk':
            $lang_file = 'sk.php';
            break;
            case 'cs':
            $lang_file = 'cs.php';
            break;
            default:
            $lang_file = 'cs.php';
        }
        include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
```

AFter this if I add something like: `echo $lang['YES']` to constructor it will display translate of it.

If I do add same echo to my other method I get error that $lang is undefined. 
So my question is how this work? How i can give all my methods in one class same variabile without using GLOBAL variabiles?

Thanks

EDITED:
for example cs.php looks like:

```
$lang = array();

//All
$lang['YES'] = 'Ano';
$lang['NO'] = 'Ne';
$lang['NOT_AVALIABLE'] = 'Není k dispozici';
$lang['CURRENCY'] = 'Měna';
```

Start of my function looks like:

```
  public function fetchByVinAxnmrss($con) {
     $success = false;
     if($this->vin){
     try{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_cases WHERE vin = :vin ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 60";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo"<tr>";
                echo  "<td class='number'>".$row['claimnumber']."</td>";
                echo $this->lang['AXNMRS_CASE_CREATED_DATE'];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: I see no OOP in your code. Basically you set `$this->lang` in `__construct` and than in other method you do `echo $this->lang;`

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for answer, but check my EDIT, $lang is getting from included FILE not from contructor other variabile, is it changing anything?

Answer (score 1):

pass your `$lang` variable through constructor.

```
class YourClass {

   public $lang;
   public function __construct($lang) {
      $this->lang = $lang;
   }
}

$yourClass = new YourClass($lang)
```

Within your function try something like below:

```
public function fetchByVinAxnmrss($con) {
     global $lang; // grab $lang here and use later
     $success = false;
     ......
}
```

Comment: I'm already giving function parameter $con so is there some other way (editing my question and adding start of my method there...

Comment: Thanks a lot, how ever I want to avoid using global variable. Is there some other way?